# Code execution prior to loading an url from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, openurl

If you call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com"]];
```

it seems to automatically quit your app -- bypassing the dealloc, viewDidDisappear, or any other functions.

Is there a way to put any code between this call and the Safari (or Phone or Email) launch, without having to put a timer before every openURL call?

====

EDIT: I need to call something only if one particular view is closed -- whether it's closed "politely", or abruptly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting something in the

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

method in your `UIApplicationDelegate`?

Comment: That's a good idea.  I was hoping to have it hit when a specific view gets killed...

Comment: Yup -- that worked.  It's kind of a hack (for my app) but that's what I'll use if nobody has any other suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

Why not put up a "launching Safari" screen, do what you need to, and then call the openURL method when all the work you need to do is done?

That said, since a user can also just press the Home button at any time you should be saving data as you go anyway.